# How to remove Jersey and Apache ResponseImpl Collision?

Tags: glassfish, jersey, cxf

I have prepared a sample camel rest web application. When i deploy it in Glassfish, i'm getting  error as like below. How to resolve this?

```
<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"><ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ResponseImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl</ns1:faultstring></ns1:XMLFault>
```

Answer (score 0):

The WAR file you're deploying probably contains Apache CXF.  Both Jersey and CXF are JAX-RS implementations and Jersey is built into Glassfish.  Having two JAX-RS implementations on the classpath is causing a problem.

Assuming that you're using Maven, try replacing your CXF dependency with a dependency on the JAX-RS API or on Jersey.  Mark the dependency as `<scope>provided</scope>` to avoid including it in your WAR file since Glassfish will provide it.